# Error:Key was rejected by service on modprobe msr

Tags: 16.04

I am getting `Key was rejected by service` error message when I do `modprobe msr`. I tried removing and installing `msr` again, but it did not solved the problem. 
Anyone knows what could be root cause of this error and how to fix it?

```
modprobe msr
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'msr': Key was rejected by service
```

System Details:

```
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS" 

#uname -a
Linux SR2B06 4.4.0-116-generic #140-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 12 21:23:04 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: This can happen when the module is incorrectly signed or if the module has been corrupted somehow. Are you still having this problem? Did it go away when you installed later Linux kernels or does it only happen with one linux version?